# gradle order of tasks: PreBuild vs JavaCompile

Tags: android, gradle

I want to build "native" code and pack it into apk.

So I wrote such gradle code:

```
def archsInfo = [/*some arches*/];
archsInfo.each { arch_name ->
  tasks.create(name: "MyNativeBuild${arch_name}", type: Exec, description: "Building core for ${arch_name}") {
    //..something
  }
  //1
  tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn "MyNativeBuild${arch_name}"
  }
  //2
  preBuild.dependsOn "MyNativeBuild${arch_name}"
}
```

The problem/mysterious for me part is marked as "//1" and "//2".

At first I wrote only "//1" without "//2".
"MyNativeBuild..." task was executed, but not before "java part compilation", for example if run `gradle clean build` it works, but in output apk there is no ".so" libraries, but they were builded without problem, so the problem was only in "merge" task that put ".so" files into ".apk". Looks like, at the moment when "merge" task run they not exists.

After I add "//2" all start work fine.

So question what do "//1" part, what is "JavaCompile",
and why "JavaCompile" stuff can be run after task that merge artefacts of build into final apk?